# Запятые при синонимах

Tags: пунктуация

Нужны ли запятые в этом предложении?

Лактат - побочный продукт при экстремальной анаэробной работе мышц.

Этот вопрос стоит из-за того, что анаэробная работа мышц - это всегда экстремальная работа мышц. Слово "экстремальная" можно было вообще убрать. Но я вставил его, так как не каждый, для кого написан текст, поймёт выражение "анаэробная работа мышц".

Answer (score 1):

**Лактат – побочный продукт при  анаэробной, экстремальной работе мышц.**

Прилагательные оформлены **как однородные** (ставится  запятая), так как обозначают **сближенные признаки** (если аэробные, то всегда экстремальные).

Для справок

Основная особенность анаэробных «бескислородных» нагрузок – это высокая интенсивность, кратковременность, максимальное напряжение. Во время таких упражнений организм практически не получает кислород, в результате чего растрачивается большое количество энергии, изъятой из мышц. Упражнения выполняются в очень быстром темпе короткими подходами.

Comment: Вы поменяли местами слова "экстремальной" и "анаэробной" по какой-то причине или просто по ошибке?

Comment: Нет, не ошибка, я их переставила по значимости: на первом месте  название, на втором - основное свойство.